# How do I modify the output of a script with php?

Tags: php, javascript, scripting

Maybe it's a stupid question but I have this script:

```
<script language="javascript">
document.write('<a class="white-link" href="?s=' + geoip_city() + '">¿Estás en ' + geoip_city() +'?</a>');
</script>
```

and I simply want to remove accents of all characters of "geoip_city()" using strtr. Normally I know how to do it but I'm not very sure this time since it's a script. I always use this to remove the accents:

```
<?php
$text = "    ";
$trans = array("á" => "a", "é" => "e", "í" => "i", "ó" => "o", "ú" => "u");
echo strtr($text, $trans);
?>
```

How do I do it?

If it's not clear please ask.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is `geoip_city()` a javascript function? If so, you'll need to re-implement your translation function in javascript, which is not difficult.

Comment: Thanks, I'm closer to do it now. It's a wordpress plugin I'll try to search for the code. I also have a shortcode "[mmjs-city]" to retrieve the city. Can I style that one through PHP? Or do I also have to change the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to reimplement (at least a basic version) the `strtr` PHP function in javascript. The function is fairly simple, you accept a translation table that maps original to new, then replace all instances of the original values with their respective new values.

```
function trans(text, table) {
    for(var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        var entry = table[i];
        text = text.replace(new RegExp(entry[0], 'g'), entry[1]);
    }

    return text;
}
```

You can use it directly like so:

```
var $trans = [
    ['a','b'],
    ['c','d']
];

alert(trans('acdc cats pajamas', $trans));
```

Like I said, the `trans` function is fairly simple. It iterates over every entry in the supplied translation table, and turns the first element in the entry into a regular expression. The reason it turns it into a regular expression (using `new RegExp`) is because of the `'g'` option, which allows you to replace every match, instead of just the first one found.

And an example way to use it in your exact circumstance:

```
<script>
function trans(text, table) {
    for(var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        var entry = table[i];
        text = text.replace(new RegExp(entry[0], 'g'), entry[1]);
    }

    return text;
}

var trans_table = [
    ["á", "a"],
    ["é", "e"],
    ["í", "i"],
    ["ó", "o"],
    ["ú", "u"]
];

var geoip_city_trans = trans(geoip_city(), trans_table);

document.write('<a class="white-link" href="?s=' + geoip_city_trans + '">¿Estás en ' + geoip_city_trans +'?</a>');

</script>
```

*Note*: I would suggest having the translation table and the actual `trans` function in an external script that's included into this page, versus defining it where you want to print the anchor.

Comment: Thanks for the really complete answer!

Comment: @Liso22: Not a problem. Just trying to do my part for SO.